# Word Documents Will Not Open After Downloading Using Apache Commons and Java FTP

Tags: java, ftp

I have followed the Apache tutorial for downloading documents from FTP using Java. I have tried two methods and both of them download the files and the file sizes are reported to be the same as the size that I see in the FTP client if I inspect the files with Filezilla. However, when I get the files on my local disk and then go to open them, Word throws an error and asks if I want to recover the document. Even if recovery did work, I need the files to be downloaded properly in the first place. Can someone shed some light on why this may be happening?

Here is the source:

```
    private void downloadAllFiles() throws IOException{
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    client.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpDirectory);
    client.setFileStructure(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);  
    FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles();
    for(FTPFile f : files) {
        if(f.isFile())
            downloadFile(f);
    }
}

    private void downloadFile(FTPFile ftpFile) throws IOException{
    File saveLocation = new File(fileStorageDir);
    if(!saveLocation.exists())
        saveLocation.mkdirs();
    File downloadFile = new File(fileStorageDir + "\\" + ftpFile.getName());
    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
    InputStream inputStream = client.retrieveFileStream(ftpFile.getName());
    byte[] bytesArray = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) !=-1) {
        outputStream.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    boolean success = client.completePendingCommand();
    if (success) {
        System.out.println("File has been downloaded successfully.");
    }
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

There are also odd characters in the file names. On the FTP server, it looks like this

[How the Filenames Should Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz8Js.png)

When I save them via Java (either method I tried), they have strange characters in the filenames I want removed:

[Local File Names With Odd Characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuLdC.png)

Any advice on either of these problems would be much appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For fixing the weird file names:

```
client.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: That fixed that issue too. Thank you.

Comment: This is not an answer to question *"Word Documents Will Not Open After Downloading Using Apache Commons and Java FTP"*

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

not

```
client.setFileStructure(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: Thank you for that. You're right. It works now. I still have the odd chars in the file names that get downloaded but at least they open.